# CodeIgniter - form validation and POST data

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a form that displays questions from a questionnaire.  Some questions are True/False (radio buttons) but some are free text input.  Each questionnaire can have any number of questions, which are stored in a lookup table along with the answer provided by the user.  To take advantage of CodeIgniters form validation library, I figured I would use an array for the input names and store the primary key of the survey question as the index:

View:

```
<input type="radio" name="question[<?=$id;?>]" value="<?=$answer?> <?=set_radio('question['. $id . ']', $answer) ?> />
```

Controller:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('question[]', 'Questions', 'required');
```

CodeIgniter doesn't seem to validate radio buttons properly when there is no default value set. Any ideas on whether or not I am doing this correctly?

Answer (score 2):

**Reference:**
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#arraysasfields

Check the arrays as fields reference, but you need to call the specific array, if your input is `question[pie]`, your validation needs to check for `question[pie]` and not `questions[]`.

I'm just making assumptions here as I don't know what you get as a response or what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have several true/false questions on my form,  and the names are dynamically generated:

    `question[11]`, `question[13]`, `question[15]`, etc.

The validation of `$this->form_validation->set_rules('question[]', 'Questions', 'required');` does appear to work but only if no radio buttons are selected. As soon as one is selected, all of the others pass validation.

Comment: well if you validate `question[]` you validate the ENTIRE array (so a single TRUE) makes the `required` TRUE.  You need to dynamically create single `..validation->set_rules('question[XX]')` for each question in your form. Don't run it on the root array `question[]`